# How to actually apply martingales when conditioning on a random variable (not filtration)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

For a Galton-Watson process, I've shown that $\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}$ is a martingale i.e. $E[\frac{Z_{n+1}}{\mu^{n+1}}|\mathcal{F}_n]=\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}$.

However, I want to show that, for $n>m$,
$$E[Z_{n}|Z_m]=\mu^{n-m}Z_m.$$
But I don't understand how to compute the right-hand side using the knowledge that $\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}$ is a martingale. I have been messing around with it for a little while, but I can't reach it.

Comment: It's because $(Z_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a Markov chain. Your equation is true by the Markov property.

Comment: @Mason what about: 
$$E[Z_{n}|Z_m] = E[E[Z_{n}|Z_{n-1}] |Z_m] = E[ \mu Z_{n-1} |Z_m] = E[E[Z_{n-1}|Z_{n-2}] |Z_m] = E[ \mu^{2}Z_{n-2} |Z_m] = ... =
\mu^{n-m}Z_m$$ 
(the "..." repeated until reaching $Z_m$)

Comment: How are you justifying the first equality? We don't have $\sigma(Z_{n - 1}) \subset \sigma(Z_m)$ and we don't have $\sigma(Z_m) \subset \sigma(Z_{n - 1})$, so the tower property isn't able to justify that.

Comment: @Mason is that not satisfied? Since it's a Galton-Watson branching process, so $Z_n$ is larger than $Z_{n-1}$ (and $Z_m$ since $n>m$)

Comment: @Mason, is there a more straightforward way to show it? I don't understand why it's simply true by the Markov property

Comment: $Z_n$ is not necessarily larger than $Z_{n - 1}$; and how does that help you anyway? The Markov property yields $E(Z_n \mid Z_m) = E(Z_n \mid \mathcal{F}_m)$, and then the martingale property yields $E(Z_n \mid \mathcal{F}_m) = \mu^{n - m}Z_m$. The most straightforward way is to show that $(Z_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a Markov chain.